# Error when evaluating pretrained model in Tensorflow object-detection (tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError:)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, runtime-error, object-detection-api

I am trying to evaluate a pretrained tensorflow object section model on my video data.

As per with my previous question which was solved I have a further error  on this script

```
python /Users/user_name/PycharmProjects/ObjDectCount/Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/legacy/eval.py --logtostderr --checkpoint_dir=test_ckpt --eval_dir=/Users/user_name/Documents/1426-1200reduced.avi --pipelineline_config_path=/samples/configs/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config
```

Resulting In this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user_name/PycharmProjects/ObjDectCount/Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/legacy/eval.py", line 142, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/user_name/.conda/envs/ObjDectCount/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/Users/user_name/.conda/envs/ObjDectCount/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user_name/PycharmProjects/ObjDectCount/Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/legacy/eval.py", line 103, in main
    tf.gfile.Copy(config, os.path.join(FLAGS.eval_dir, name), overwrite=True)
  File "/Users/user_name/.conda/envs/ObjDectCount/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 474, in copy
    copy_v2(oldpath, newpath, overwrite)
  File "/Users/user_name/.conda/envs/ObjDectCount/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 492, in copy_v2
    compat.as_bytes(src), compat.as_bytes(dst), overwrite, status)
  File "/Users/user_name/.conda/envs/ObjDectCount/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: ; No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo

```
pipelineline_config_path=/samples/configs/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config
```

should be

```
pipeline_config_path=/samples/configs/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config
```